# Find the nearest vector in a dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dictionnary where one word is a key for a vector of size 100;
and a vector (also size 100).
How can I get the dictionnary key which vector is the nearest to myVector (in the sense of euclidian distance) ?

I have started to make an implementation by hand to calculate the euclidian distance between myVector and each vector of myDict and keep the minimum, but I fear it will be terribly inefficient (myDict is very large), and I think there might be a built-in implementation of such function.

```
var myDict = {
    "a":[-0.03,-0.24,0.72,...0.39,0.08,0.04],
    "b":[-0.10,0.11,0.59,...-0.54,0.67,0.10],
    "c":[-0.67,0.53,0.12,...0.61,-0.96,0.63],
    "d":[-0.76,0.05,0.81,...-0.36,0.39,0.66]
}
myVector = [0.10,-0.20,0.80,...0.60,-0.40]
```

(I'd prefer not to use an external library)

Answer (score 0):

You could take the distance with [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) and get the one with the smallest distance.

```js
var dict = { a: [-0.03, -0.24, 0.72, 0.39, 0.08, 0.04], b: [-0.10, 0.11, 0.59, -0.54, 0.67, 0.10], c: [-0.67, 0.53, 0.12, 0.61, -0.96, 0.63], d: [-0.76, 0.05, 0.81, -0.36, 0.39, 0.66] },
    vector = [0.10, -0.20, 0.80, 0.60, -0.40],
    hypot = Math.hypot(...vector),
    closest = Object.keys(dict).reduce((a, b) =>
        Math.abs(hypot - Math.hypot(...dict[a])) < Math.abs(hypot - Math.hypot(...dict[b])) ? a : b);

console.log(closest);
```